# Why are this == other and and this.hashcode == other.hashcode() giving different results?

Tags: java, equals

I have a class with the following `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o)
{
  if (this == o) { return true; }
  if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) { return false; }

  Phrases that = (Phrases) o;

  if (this.hashCode() == o.hashCode()) { return true; } //retry clover coverage test
  if (exitMsg != null ? !exitMsg.equals(that.exitMsg) : that.exitMsg != null)
  { return false; }
  if (introMsg != null ? !introMsg.equals(that.introMsg) : that.introMsg != null)
  { return false; }
  if (msg != null ? !msg.equals(that.msg) : that.msg != null)
  { return false; }
  if (phrase != null ? !phrase.equals(that.phrase) : that.phrase != null)
  { return false; }
  if (title != null ? !title.equals(that.title) : that.title != null)
  { return false; }

  return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode()
{
  int result = phrase != null ? phrase.hashCode() : 0;
  result = 31 * result + (title != null ? title.hashCode() : 0);
  result = 31 * result + (introMsg != null ? introMsg.hashCode() : 0);
  result = 31 * result + (msg != null ? msg.hashCode() : 0);
  result = 31 * result + (exitMsg != null ? exitMsg.hashCode() : 0);
  return result;
}
```

I was trying to figure out why *clover* couldn't tell that my hashcode method had run.  I added the line:

```
if (this.hashCode() == o.hashCode()) { return true; } //retry clover coverage test
```

according to clover for everytime this equals method ran `if (this == o) { return true; }` was **false** but `if (this.hashCode() == o.hashCode()) { return true; }` was **true**.

---

**Question:**

Why are `this == o` and `this.hashCode() == o.hashCode()` not evaluating with the same result?

Comment: Because the objects have the same hash but aren’t the same pointer?

Comment: @U2744SNOWFLAKE, Sorry I should have posted that `hashCode()` was overridden as well.  I've updated the question with the code for it too.

Comment: You can create two different objects that have the same hash code (i.e. `hashCode()` returns the same value).  In this case, using `==` on the object references will return `false`.  But of course comparing `hashCode()` results is true because you're comparing the same integer to itself.

Comment: Why do you think `==` should return `true`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I didn't say `==` should return `true`. After reading some of the answers, especially @Jack I think it was a misunderstanding. I thought `==` compared hashCode values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A hash code, by definition, contains less information than the source data. This means that collisions are possible, and in that case you will have two objects with same hash code but which are not equal.

The general requirement of Java `hashCode()` are in the opposite direction:

- two objects for which `equals` relation holds must produce same hash code (the opposite is not true)
- if two objects are different, they are not required to produce a different hash code at all

**Basically the point is that you can't use the hash code as an unique identifier** (indeed JDK data structures manage collisions internally).

This nothing has to do with `==` since it compares just references (memory addresses) of the object, for which `hashCode()` and equals will be trivially the same.

If you take a look at your `hashCode()` you can see that if all fields but one are null, but which field is different, the hash code computed is the same, which clearly proves the fact that you can easily generate collision.

If you want something stronger you should consider using [`MessageDigest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html) which produces digests much longer than an `int` (so able to hold more information = less likely to have a collision). But you won't have any guarantees even with them.

Comment: Turns out I had a fundamental misunderstanding of Java.  I thought `==` compared `hashcode()` values.

Comment: In java, the only operator that will call a function is +, which calls toString() when used as a concatenation operator. There is no other operator overloading in java.

Answer (score 0):

`==` does not call `.equals`.

In fact, the two are completely different, overlapping only in objects that have not overriden Object's default (bad) implementation.

`==` just checks to see if the too objects are equivalent pointers.

`.equals` runs a method like the one you showed.

Replacing `==` with `.equals` should solve your problem

Comment: Huh? The OP specifically mentioned == and was wondering why hashCode was not being called. The reason is that java does not do operator overloading and that == does not call .equals.

Comment: Sorry--now that I look at the question again, it's not entirely clear what he's really asking.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to say. Do you want to suggest to use `equals` inside `equals` (since code OP is asking about is inside of this method)? This is straight way to infinite recursion and overflow of stack.

Comment: the name of the question, as well as part of its text, refer to this==other, which will not call anything.

Answer (score 0):

Step back a little...

Consider the contract of `equals()` and `hashCode()`. Consider the fact that the contract is one way only: if you implement both in a class then the requirement is that if two instances of a class are equal then they must have the same hashcode.

**What it does not say is that if two instances have the same hashcode then they must be equal. Yet you assume that in your .equals() implementation!**

And yet in your code, there is:

```
// WRONG!
if (this.hashCode() == o.hashCode()) { return true; }
```

Here is an example of a perfectly valid `hashCode()` method:

```
public int hashCode()
{
    return 42;
}
```

Now, I believe you can see where the problem lies with your .equals() method...

---

Assuming Java 7, here is how you would write both methods; since both account for `null`, this is easy (on the other hand, you should avoid `null`s when you can; ultimately, `null` is nothing but trouble):

```
@Override
public final int hashCode()
{
    return Objects.hash(phrase, title, introMsg, msg, errorMsg);
}

@Override
public final boolean equals(final Object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    final MyClass other = (MyClass) obj;
    return Objects.equals(phrase, other.phrase)
        && Objects.equals(title, other.title)
        && Objects.equals(introMsg, other.introMsg)
        && Objects.equals(msg, other.msg)
        && Objects.equals(errorMsg, other.errorMsg);
}
```

Comment: Actually I'm using Java 6.  The line you flag as *wrong* I only added as a test because I was trying to figure something out hence the `//retry clover coverage test` comment.  I'm not asking for help with my equals()/hashcode() methods. I was just curious as to why `==` and `==` against `.hashcode()` were inconsistent.

Comment: `==` only compares object references; that `o1 != o2` does NOT MEAN that `o1.equals(o2)` is false! And this has nothing to do with `hashCode()`! You seem to be missing some fundamentals here